# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

**GOAL**

Eu tenho duas tabelas (tb_get_gap, tb_getCountSRVS), onde na primeira tabela conto para obter os valores desejados e na segunda tenho valores inteiros, só quero pegar o valores das duas e subtrair

**QUERY**

```
select 
(cast(srvs as int) - (SELECT COUNT(*) hostname FROM tb_get_gap
LEFT JOIN tb_get_customers
ON tb_get_gap.customer = tb_get_customers.cust_cmdb WHERE tb_get_customers.customer in (select customer from tb_get_customers) and tb_get_gap.exception = 'NO'
GROUP BY tb_get_gap.customer ORDER BY tb_get_gap.customer ASC)) 
from tb_getCountSRVS order by cust_code asc
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>[Error] Script lines: 1-6 --------------------------
 ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
 Line: 1
```

Comment: Você não teria que correlacionar sua subquery com algum valor da tabela tb_getCountSRVS? Sua subquery está contando para cada valor de customer existente em tb_get_gap e retornando tal lista.

Comment: Acredito que sim, pois se eu coloco LIMIT 1 dentro da subquery ele me retorna os valores, porem decrementa o mesmo valores de todos.

Comment: Pois então verifique qual campo da tabela tb_getCountSRVS se refere o valor srvs para você correlacionar com sua subquery (chutando, já que não conheço suas tabelas, eu diria que é customer).

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) hostname - cast(tb_getCountSRVS.srvs as int)
FROM tb_get_gap
LEFT JOIN tb_getCountSRVS
ON tb_get_gap.customer = tb_getCountSRVS.cust_code WHERE tb_getCountSRVS.customer in (select customer from tb_getCountSRVS) and tb_get_gap.exception = 'NO'
GROUP BY tb_get_gap.customer ORDER BY tb_get_gap.customer ASC

Comment: OUTPUT:

>[Error] Script lines: 1-5 --------------------------
 ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"
 Line: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chutando, já que você não forneceu informações suficientes como é recomendado neste site [[exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), penso que pode ser:

```
SELECT (cast(srvs AS int) - 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) hostname FROM tb_get_gap
    LEFT JOIN tb_get_customers ON tb_get_gap.customer = tb_get_customers.cust_cmdb 
    WHERE tb_get_customers.customer =  tb_getCountSRVS.customer AND tb_get_gap.exception = 'NO'
    )
) 
FROM tb_getCountSRVS ORDER BY cust_code ASC;
```

Comment: Opa, deu certo, muito obrigado!!